# three.js OBJ MTL Loader with ambient light not working

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

So even in the example "webgl_loader_obj_mtl" the ambient light is not being used. You can comment it out and it makes no difference. It relies on the directional light. If you comment out the directional nothing displays (since ambient is not casting color).

Is there a way to fix this?

Using only directional light creates glare/reflections that make the object look plastic, and only lights certain areas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because if you look at the .mtl file the Ka parameter (ambient of material) is everywhere 0.00. Try changing it to 0.2 and you will see ambient light effects.

Comment: TY! I am still learning 3D rendering, so i would have never guessed it to be that simple!